# How can i add a field for e.g. an alt text to every image in an array in Sanity?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

i am trying to add a string object to every image in an array in sanity, but i am not successfull altough my solution makes pretty much sense to me:

```
{
      name: 'images',
      title: 'Images',
      type: 'array',
      of: [
        {
          name: 'image',
          type: 'image',
          title: 'Image',
          options: {
            hotspot: true,
          },
          fields: [
            {
              name: 'alt',
              type: 'string',
              title: 'Alternative text',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
```

[image: This is what it looks like in studio]

All what is displayed in sanity studio is the field to upload an image, can somebody help me with what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an object type:

```js
{
  name: 'images',
  title: 'Images',
  type: 'array',
  of: [
    {
      type: 'object',
      name: 'person',
      fields: [
        {
          name: 'alt',
          type: 'string',
          title: 'Alternative text',
        },
        {
          name: 'image',
          type: 'image',
          title: 'Image',
          options: {
            hotspot: true,
          },
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```